# $I$ is a two sided ideal in $A$, $L$ and $M$ are $A$-modules such that $L \subset M$. If $l\in L$ and $l\in MI$ then $l \in LI$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$A$ is an Artinian ring, $I$ is a two sided ideal. I know that $L \subset M$ are $A$-modules, and that $l \in L \cap MI$. Is it true that $l \in LI$? If is not true, can I have an example where it does not happen?

Comment: L and M are right A-modules.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at $A=F[x]/(x^2)$ with $A=M$, and $L=I=(x)/(x^2)$